# How to update state of all childs rendered with map() inside a parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, viro-react

my goal is to time the visibility of child components based on the playback time of a video.
This components, called InfoElement, are rendered thanks to map method.

```
{this.props.sceneNavigator.viroAppProps.tours[this.state.tourId].scenes[this.state.sceneId].infoElements.map((infoElement, key) => {
return (
    <InfoElement 
        content={{uri: infoElement.poiImage}}
        startingTime = {infoElement.startingTime}
        endingTime = {infoElement.endindTime}
        contentCardScale={[5, 5, 5]} 
        position={polarToCartesian(infoElement.coordinate)}/>
    )
    })}
```

Inside the parent, there is a callback, `_onUpdateTime(currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds, totalPlayBackDurationInSeconds)` that is called when the current playback position of the video has changed.

```
<Viro360Video
    source={{uri:this.props.sceneNavigator.viroAppProps.tours[this.state.tourId].scenes[this.state.sceneId].backgroundSource}}
    onBufferEnd={this.onLoadEnded}
    onUpdateTime={this._onUpdateTime}
    rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
    onError={this.onError}/>

    _onUpdateTime(currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds, totalPlayBackDurationInSeconds) {
  this.setState({
                  visible : false,
               });

           console.log(currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds);
        }
```

What i want to do is to compare the `currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds` with `startingTime` and `endingTime` and make the infoElement component visible only if`currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds` is between `startingTime` and `endingTime`. My problem is that i don't have just one infoElement, but a list, so i don't know how to refer to each of them. The idea would be to update the state of each of them, but i have no idea how to do that. Any advice? Thanks to all that will answer me.

Comment: Please also add the code of the callback used in parent component.

Comment: As for your question, If you have any unique id in your array then you can use it in state variable for unique reference of any `InfoElement` that you are rendering.

Comment: Can you add `currentPlaybackTimeInSeconds` as a prop to the `InfoElement` component to selectively render it? Or use a different array function, like filter, to do the comparison in the parent component and return a filtered array of `InfoElement`s that have start/end times that straddle the current playback time?

Comment: If all of them are sharing the same state for visiblility,pass the prop from parent to all the childs and toggle the visible state in parents method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inverse your thinking on this one. What you should be doing is telling each InfoElement what the current time is, and then they change their rendered output based on that time. Something like this:

```js
const React = require('react');
const {useState,useCallback} = React;

const InfoElement = ({currentTime,startingTime,endingTime}) => {
    if(currentTime >= startingTime && currentTime < endingTime){
        return (
            <>
                {/* Your render code here*/}
            </>
        );
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

const App = ({sceneNavigator}) => {
    const [currentTime,setCurrentTime] = useState(-1);
    const [tourId,setTourId] = useState(-1);
    const [sceneId,setSceneId] = useState(-1);

    const onUpdateTime = useCallback((time) => {
        setCurrentTime(time);
    },[]);

    let infoElements = [];
    if(sceneNavigator.viroAppProps.tours[tourId] != null && sceneNavigator.viroAppProps.tours[tourId].scenes[sceneId] != null){
        infoElements = sceneNavigator.viroAppProps.tours[tourId].scenes[sceneId].infoElements;
    }

    return (<>
        <Viro360Video
            onUpdateTime={onUpdateTime}

        />

        {infoElements.map((infoElement, key) => (
            <InfoElement
                key={`infoElement-${key}`}
                content={{uri: infoElement.poiImage}}
                startingTime = {infoElement.startingTime}
                currentVideoTime={currentTime}
                endingTime = {infoElement.endindTime}
                contentCardScale={[5, 5, 5]} 
                position={polarToCartesian(infoElement.coordinate)}/>
            )
        )}
    </>);
}
```

In this, you can see that we're hooking to the `Viro360Video` `onUpdateTime` and setting a `currentTime` state. We then pass the `currentTime` to each `InfoElement`. Inside the `InfoElement` we check the `currentTime` passed in against the `startingTime` and `endingTime`, if we're inside those bounds, we render our elements, otherwise, we return null.

**Notes**

1. I'm using hooks inside functional components instead of using react classes. See their usage here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
2. I used Fragments (`<></>`) instead of a `div` or a `View` since I don't know if you're targeting React Native or ReactDOM or some other rendering engine.